# Cryptomatte image sequence

Tags: compositing-nodes, cryptomatte

i've an issue with my cryptomatte , eveything was ok until strangely the cryptommate node stop working with image sequence .. it's very strange because if i load one frame as a single image its working and i can pick object but if i want to load the full sequence its became black and i cant pick anything .. i've try to open it in a older project with no cryptomatte issue and its loading the sequence but some frame missing a the end . Am i doing something wrong or is there an issue with cryptomatte and blender compositing ?
thanks

Comment: OK so apparently i have to edit myself the start frame and stuff to make it work ..